# React - Obtener el comportamiento de elemento superior en hijos

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hola gracias por la ayuda de antemano. Explico el comportamiento que deseo lograr en react. Aqui dejo el sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-0ntxmj?file=/src/App.js:0-639 para una mejor comprension. El comportamiento del codigo es el siguiente:

Hay un div marcado con un borde de 1px a dentro de el hay un boton y otro div donde rederizara un array. Al hacer click en el botton se agrega ese mismo boton al array y se renderiza a la par del primero. Al hacer varios click en el primer boton esto generara una columna de botones a la par del primer boton. Hasta aqui todo bien.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer click en cualquiera de los botones de la columna se genere otra columna de botones a la par del boton al que hacemos click. Y asi sucesivamente. En este punto, estoy atrapado. Gracias.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [btnCount, setBtnCount] = useState([]);

  const style = {
    maxWidth: "100px",
    display: "flex",
    padding: "10px",
    border: "solid 1px"
  };

  function handleAdd() {
    setBtnCount(btnCount.concat(btn));
  }

  const btn = <button onClick={handleAdd}>Click</button>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={style}>
        <div style={{ margin: "5px" }}>{btn}</div>
        <div>
          {btnCount.map((e, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>{e}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Quieres generar botones con cualquier btn generado?

Comment: el btn es una simulacion de un componente react en un array, cada btn generado por el primer boton debe ser capaz de crear su propia columna de botones y asi al infinito. Luego ese btn lo remplazare por un componente

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con que la handleAdd se destruye y se crea siempre... los handleAdd del array no apuntan al mismo handleAdd del componente renderizado. No estoy seguro pero intenta usar useCallback. O useRef para guardar la función

Comment: Pienso, que los botones generados por el primer btn deben tener su propio array para guardar sus propios botones. cada boton debe ser capaz de generar su propio grupo de botones.

Comment: Entonces tienes que poder pasar un nuevo estado array y nuevo componente. En el array solo hay de momento un <DIV><BTN>... no hay ningún array nuevo

Comment: Si habria de buscar una forma de generar estados individuales para cada btn, sin perder la funcionalidad inicial.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135501/discussion-between-usiel-and-jose-javier-sanahuja).

Comment: Nunca he intentado llamar un componente dentro sí mismo. Creo no funcionaría. Y si cambiamos la lógica? Usas 2 estados uno para un crecimiento horizontal y otro para un crecimiento vertical? Y pasas el handleAdd por props para evitar el error anterior